# Email Regular expression issue while using special characters

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I have created the following regular expression for validating my email

```
- (BOOL)isValidEmail
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:self];
}
```

But it fails when i enter following:

```
b. !@#$%^ bfv@mn.cn
```

Is there any issue with my regular expression?

Comment: You pretty much cannot validate email addresses... the only way to know for sure is to send out a confirmation email.

Comment: @luk2302 i dont think so..

Comment: @Umair !@ is not a valid email address

Comment: feel free to try to validate email addresses and be in a world of pain - go ahead and try the other regex

Comment: while "horst@bayern" is a valid email address that you would currently reject - do not even try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's work perfect for me.

```
 NSString *mailreg=@"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *mailtest=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",mailreg];
return [mailtest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
```