# iOS Email address validation not accepting .in

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Validating Email address with regex not accepting two character extensions like .in .co etc

```
BOOL stricterFilter = NO;
NSString *stricterFilterString = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";
NSString *laxString = @"^.+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*$";
NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
```

Comment: see this link once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428304/email-validation-on-textfield-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493418/email-regular-expression-issue-while-using-special-characters/34493537#34493537

Comment: it's accepting .in as a valid Email.

Comment: see this patterens http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
#pragma mark - Valid Email
+ (BOOL)isValidEmail:(NSString*)email
{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
}
```

Comment: I have checked it and working perfectly. You need to check your code.

Comment: This regex is not correct with `xyz@company.email` format

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check in `laxString` look like following:

```
 NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
```

Then Check that must be working

Following is my working code:

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)checkString
{
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

Comment: still no change @nitin gohel

Comment: i made small mistake @nitin, plus one for quick response

Answer (score 0):

Validate email usind below function

```
 - (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString *)email
    {
        NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
        return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];
    }
```

after validating email check **.in** at the end of email or not with below piece in code

```
NSString *lastThreeChar = [yourNewString substringFromIndex:[txt_Email.text length] - 3];
    if ([lastThreeChar isEqualToString:@".in"])
     {
      // email_id contain .in
     }
    else{
        // email_id dosen't contain .in
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)validateEmail {
    //Email address field should give an error when the email address begins with ".","-","_" .
    // Works well with @me.com.

    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z._-]{0,64})+[A-Z0-9a-z]+@[A-Z0-9a-z]+([A-Za-z0-9.-]{0,64})+([A-Z0-9a-z])+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];   
    return ([emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:self.text] && self.text.length <= 64 && ([self.text rangeOfString:@".."].location == NSNotFound));
}
```